# Почему функция генерации случайных строк в цикле не срабатывает?

Tags: c#, c#-faq, генерация-случайных-данных

Функция генерации рандомных строк в цикле генерирует только одну строку и заполняет массив. При этом если смотреть через отладку, то все нормально.

```
static string GetRandomString(int Length)
{
    string Alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Length - 1);
    int Position = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
    {
        Position = rnd.Next(0, Alphabet.Length - 1);
        sb.Append(Alphabet[Position]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

    string[] s = new string[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        s[i] = GetRandomString(6);
    }
```

Comment: Кстати, `rnd.Next(0, Alphabet.Length - 1)` неправильно, т. к. верхняя граница не включается. Пишите просто `rnd.Next(0, Alphabet.Length)` или даже `rnd.Next(0, Alphabet.Length)`.

Answer (score 4):

Смотрите. Вычисление случайных чисел происходит так. У генератора есть текущее число (seed), которое инициализируется при создании `Random`. При вычислении следующего числа seed преобразуется по какому-то закону, и из нового значения seed строится выдаваемое наружу случайное число.

При этом, понятно, если начальные значения seed одинаковые, то и вся последовательность случайных чисел тоже будет одинаковой.

Судя по всему, вы пользуетесь .NET Framework, а в нём конструктор `new Random()` инициализирует генератор случайных чисел текущим временем.

А поскольку ваш цикл выполняется очень быстро, то текущее время не успевает «тикнуть», так что у всех ваших вызовов начальные значения seed одинаковы. Поэтому и последовательности тоже одинаковы.

Из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.1#avoiding-multiple-instantiations):

> Инциализация нескольких генераторов случайных чисел в цикле или подряд создаёт генераторы, которые скорее всего произведут одинаковые последовательности случайных чисел. В большинстве случаев это не то, на что вы рассчитываете [...].
>
> Чтобы одновременно и улучшить производительность, и избежать создания генераторов, генерирующих одну и ту же последовательность чисел, мы рекомендуем создать один объект `Random`, и генерироваить с его помощью много случайных чисел, вместо того, чтобы создавать много генераторов, и генерировать каждым из них понемногу.

В .NET Core описанного эффекта нет: `Random()` берёт случайный seed, не привязанный ко времени, поэтому данная проблема не возникла бы.

---

Что делать? Используйте общий экземпляр `Random`. Например, так:

```
static Random rnd = new Random(); // общий экземпляр
static string GetRandomString(int Length)
{
    string Alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Length - 1);
    int Position = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
    {
        Position = rnd.Next(0, Alphabet.Length - 1);
        sb.Append(Alphabet[Position]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Или переходите на .NET Core.

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение! Теперь буду больше обращаться к документации.

Comment: @ruffury: Пожалуйста! Буду рад, если помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Псевдослучайный генератор выдает одинаковые последовательности, при создании в сходных условиях, цикл очень быстро проходит - условия не успевают измениться. Можно объявлять так:

```
Random rnd = new Random(unchecked((int)(DateTime.Now.Ticks)));
```

Или создайте экземпляр `Random` вне функции и передавайте его параметром.
Должно помочь.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Ticks` - так это же почти тоже самое, что и вызывать конструктор без параметров. Лучше уж тогда `new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())`. А вообще правильно иметь один статический экземпляр на всю программу.