# Как вытащить содержимое фигурных скобок

Tags: c#

Имеется строка: `Антон,{привет|пока} как {дела|жизнь}?`

Задача вытащить из скобок содержимое и выбрать рандомное значение, так же важно сохранить слова перед скобками/за скобками. Вышла пока-что только рандомизация внутренних слов:

```
string input = "привет|пока";
Random rnd = new Random();
string[] str = input.Split('|');
string result = str[rnd.Next(0, str.Lenght)];
```

**Решение:**

```
                string subject = "{привет|пока}";
                                        char[] chars = subject.ToCharArray();
                        bool start = false;
                        string res = "";
                        string oldString = "";
                        for (int i = 0, n = chars.Length; i < n; i++)
                        {
                            char c = chars[i];
                            if (c == '}')
                            {
                                start = false;
                                Random rnd = new Random();
                                string[] r = res.Split('|');
                                oldString += r[rnd.Next(0, r.Length)];
                                res = "";
                            }
                            if (start)
                                res += c.ToString();
                            if (c == '{')
                                start = true;
                            if (!start && c != '{' && c != '}')
                                oldString += c.ToString();
                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, проще всего с регулярками.

```cs
// нам нужен нежадный захват
// внутренний текст положим в группу
static Regex regex = new Regex("{(.*?)}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "Антон, {привет|пока} как {дела|жизнь}?";
    var r = new Random();
    string expanded = regex.Replace(text, match =>
    {
        var innerText = match.Groups[1].Value;
        var alternatives = innerText.Split('|');
        var chosen = alternatives[r.Next(alternatives.Length)];
        return chosen;
    });
}
```

И посмотрите [вот сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/806233/10105) по поводу использования `Random`.