# Как получить ключ по значению?

Tags: c#

С клавиатуры вводится число от 1 до 10 и нужно по нему от вывести информацию о рандомно созданном человеке (имя, фамилия, дата рождения). И у меня возникла заминка: я не знаю как получить ключ по значению.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace people
{
class Human {

    string[] names = new string[] {"Egor", "Roman", "Vladimir", "Alexander", "Ivan", "Artyom", "Yaroslav", "Mikhail", "Arthur", "Nekita"};
    string[] secondNames = new string[] {"Vorobiev", "Strigin", "Bairamov", "Ivanov", "Petrov", "Sokolov", "Smirnov", "Popov", "Morozov", "Volkov"};       
    int[] dates = new int[] {200304, 210505, 040595, 050606, 070809, 010203, 170209, 060990, 150809, 120584};
    string _name;
    string _secondName;
    int _date;

    Random r = new Random();

    public Human()
    {
        _name = names[r.Next(0, names.Length)];
        _secondName = secondNames[r.Next(0, secondNames.Length)];
        _date = dates[r.Next(0, dates.Length)];
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public string GetSecondName()
    {
        return _secondName;
    }

    public int GetDate()
    {
        return _date;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Human h1 = new Human();
        Human h2 = new Human();
        Human h3 = new Human();
        Human h4 = new Human();
        Human h5 = new Human();
        Human h6 = new Human();
        Human h7 = new Human();
        Human h8 = new Human();
        Human h9 = new Human();
        Human h10 = new Human();


        Dictionary<Human, int> people = new Dictionary <Human, int>
        {
            {h1, 1},
            {h2, 2},
            {h3, 3},
            {h4, 4},
            {h5, 5},
            {h6, 6},
            {h7, 7},
            {h8, 8},
            {h9, 9},
            {h10, 10}
        };

        Console.Write("Введите число от 1 до 10: ");
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        
        foreach (var item in people.Values)
        {
            if (item == a)
            {
                 //конкретно здесь я не знаю что делать
            }
        }
}
}

}
```

Comment: У вас странный подход. Зачем вам вручную писать индексы? Сделайте массив/коллекцию и обращайтесь просто `people[a]`, ну а если хотите словарь, то тоже странный подход делать человека "ключом", может ключом стоит сделать `int`?

Comment: Буду знать, в c# пока новичок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    foreach (var key in people.Keys)
    {
        if (people[key] == a)
        {
             //конкретно здесь я знаю что делать
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Ключи и значения в словаре надо поменять местами:

```
var people = new Dictionary <int, Human>
{
  {1, h1},
  {2, h2},
```

Ну и потом

```
Console.Write("Введите число от 1 до 10: ");
int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
var h = p[i];
```

PS: А это - [косяк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/806229/178988):

```
Random r = new Random();
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам вовсе не нужно получать значение по ключу. Если вам внутри цикла нужно и ключ, и значение, пишите так:

```
foreach (var (key, item) in people)
{
    // тут у вас есть и ключ, и значение
}
```

Но для вашего случая даже это не нужно. Раз вам нужно получить человека п очислу, значит, в вашем словаре число должно быть ключом. Получаем вот что:

```
Dictionary<int, Human> people = new Dictionary <int, Human>
{
    {1, h1},
    {2, h2},
    {3, h3},
    {4, h4},
    {5, h5},
    {6, h6},
    {7, h7},
    {8, h8},
    {9, h9},
    {10, h10},
};

Console.Write("Введите число от 1 до 10: ");
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
var item = people[a];
```

Comment: В переменной `a` у него - целое, значение в словаре.

Comment: @Igor: А, тьфу, и правда.

Comment: @Igor: Раз так, надо развернуть словарь.

Comment: Точно. *(9 символов нужно...)*

Comment: Ну что за любители Convert'ов :(

Comment: @Qwertiy: Копипаста, сэр. Так во многих примерах начального уровня.